# Error with matchTemplate function in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, object-detection

### These are includes which I am using

```
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
```

---

### This is namespace

```
using namespace cv;
```

---

### But when I am using matchTemplate function, I am catching the following problem

```
error C3861: 'matchTemplate': identifier not found
```

---

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Additional information:
I am using OpenCV2.3

thank you for spending time to view and comment my problem

Best Regards
Hayk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need imgproc.hpp included, the one that you included has the C version only : cvMatchTemplate